# Trigger to return duplicate error in MySQL and to affect the INSERT INTO..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert-update

I am having a challenge with MySQL. As you know MySQL does not consider NULL as a duplicate value in the unique indexes.

The problem here is that I have a table but I need to enforces that no similar data to be inserted "including NULL" into the following columns 
(call_code_id, result_code_id, action_method, action_id, assign_to, assign_to_type)

You may suggest for me to add a unique index on those columns. The problem that the columns "assign_to" and "assign_id" allows NULL values. So based on MySQL definition of a unique columns the following 2 set of data are not Unique and will be allowed to be inserted
(call_code_id, result_code_id, action_method, action_id, assign_to, assign_to_type)
(1,1,'FINISH',NULL,5,2)
(1,1,'FINISH',NULL,5,2)

so even if I add a unique column, MySQL will allow those 2 rows to be inserted. But I need to prevent that for happening as my application consider those 2 rows duplicates.

I must say here that I update this table using stored procedure and I update the table using INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.

My initial solution was to add a 2 triggers on that table. First trigger for insert and the other for update. Both trigger will return error code 1062 if a similar data was found before insert or update.

That did worked somewhat! But the new challenge is that the error code 1062 that is return by the trigger is not being utilized by the INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. However, it is returning the 1062 error on the screen so it is finding the duplicates as it should. So when I execute the INSERT INTO ...... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement I get the error 1062 returned on the screen, instead it should perform an update since I am asking it to update when duplicate records are found.

Here are my triggers syntax

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `return_1062_on_duplicate_on_insert`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `return_1062_on_duplicate_on_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `inventory_engine_test`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inventory_engine_test
WHERE call_code_id = NEW.call_code_id
AND result_code_id = NEW.result_code_id
AND action_method = NEW.action_method
AND IFNULL(action_id, 0) = IFNULL(NEW.action_id, 0)
AND IFNULL(assign_to, 0) = IFNULL(NEW.assign_to, 0)
AND assign_to_type = NEW.assign_to_type
AND NEW.engine_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000'
SET MYSQL_ERRNO = 1062,
TABLE_NAME = 'inventory_engine_test',
MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate key found - return_1062_on_duplicate_on_insert trigger';
END IF;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `return_1062_on_duplicate_on_update`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `return_1062_on_duplicate_on_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `inventory_engine_test`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inventory_engine_test
WHERE call_code_id = NEW.call_code_id
AND result_code_id = NEW.result_code_id
AND action_method = NEW.action_method
AND IFNULL(action_id, 0) = IFNULL(NEW.action_id, 0)
AND IFNULL(assign_to, 0) = IFNULL(NEW.assign_to, 0)
AND assign_to_type = NEW.assign_to_type
AND NEW.engine_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000'
SET MYSQL_ERRNO = 1062,
TABLE_NAME = 'inventory_engine_test',
MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate key found - return_1062_on_duplicate_on_update trigger';
END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I get INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to consider the error return by the trigger?

Thanks

Comment: having the same question :-)